# Getting string after first comma and before second comma

Tags: java, android

I have a string like this - `"5,password,6099000,tree,city"`.

I want to extract only `password` from it. This means anything after first comma and before second comma.

How do I do this?

Comment: Show us at least what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution might be to split the string on comma:

```
String input = "5,password,6099000,tree,city";
String[] parts = input.split(",");
String password = parts[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function Split(),

```
String example = "5,password,6099000,tree,city";    
String[] parts = example.split(",");
System.out.println(parts[1]);
```

Also look here: 
[How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

## there you go

> this will work

```
 String str="5,password,6099000,tree,city"
  String parts[]=str.split(",");
    String part1 = parts[0]; // 5
    String part2 = parts[1]; //Password
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String string = "5,password,6099000,tree,city";
String subString = string.substring(2,10);
```

I assume you are a Java beginner, you may want to check

> String Manipulation